# Going from mysql statements to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I need to rewrite all my code.. I was told last time I was in here, that I needed to choose between mysqli or PDO.. now I have choosen PDO - but I must say that I don't understand NOTHING at all..

For example I have this piece of code:

```
//get the email
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

//mysql query to select field email if it's equal to the email that we check '
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT email FROM business_members WHERE email = '".$email."'"));

//if number of rows fields is bigger them 0 that means it's NOT available '
if($result['email'] == $email){
//and we send 0 to the ajax request
echo "0";
}else{
//else if it's not bigger then 0, then it's available '
//and we send 1 to the ajax request
echo "1";
}
```

Are there any sites that can help me understand a little better and I have tried to read on php-net, but it is very confusing..

Comment: Try this article: [PHP Data Object/PDO Tutorial](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing about PDO is that its object orientated. So keeping to that form and making the most of it we can create a PDO CRUD class that handles all your database query's ect.

Here is an example, custom methods/functions can be added to enhance functionality ect:

```
<?php 
Class PDO_CRUD{
    private $db;

    function __construct($host,$dbname,$user,$pass){
        $this->dbhost = $host;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->dbuser = $user;
        $this->dbpass = $pass;
    }

    private function connect(){
        if (!$this->db instanceof PDO){
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$this->dbname.';host='.$this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    /*Raw Select*/
    public function rawQuery($sql){
        $this->connect();
        return $this->db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function get($table,$fieldname=null, $id=null){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $fieldname = :id";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /*Insert*/
    public function put($table,$values){
        $this->connect();
        $fieldnames = array_keys($values[0]);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ";
        $fields = '('.implode(' ,', $fieldnames).')';
        $bound = '(:'.implode(', :', $fieldnames).')';
        $sql .= $fields.' VALUES '.$bound;

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        foreach($values as $vals){
            $statement->execute($vals);
        }
    }

    /*Update*/
    public function update($table,$fieldname, $value, $pk, $id){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $fieldname = :value WHERE $pk = :id";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
    }

    /*Update Hits*/
    public function add_hit($table,$id){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE url = :id";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
    }

    /*Delete*/
    public function delete($table,$id){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE url = :id";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
    }
}

//Then we have a nice way to access all our querys from one class.
//ini the model class
$model = new PDO_CRUD('localhost','yourDB','User','Password');

$insert = array(array('id'=>NULL,'somecol'=>'someval'));
$model->put('someTable',$insert);

//multiple inserts
$insert = array(array('id'=>NULL,'somecol'=>'someval123'),
                array('id'=>NULL,'somecol'=>'someval1234'),
                array('id'=>NULL,'somecol'=>'someval12345'));
$model->put('someTable',$insert);

//or delete a row
$model->delete('someTable',1);

//or a raw query
$model->rawQuery('DELETE FROM someTable');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP File containing the PDO functions:

```
<?php
class example {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;', 'user', 'password');
    }

    public function checkMail($email) {
        // This is the prepared SQL statement
        // The values which you want to filter for in your WHERE clause, are replaced by ?
        $sql = "SELECT
                    email
                FROM
                    business_members
                WHERE
                    email = ?";

        // Prepare the statement
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        // Bind a value to a question mark (the 1 means, the position of occurence of the question mark)
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $email);

        // Query the db, output debug info if query failed
        if(!$stmt->execute()) {
            // Only for debugging, don't use in production
            var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
        }

        // Load result to var
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Check amount of records
        if(count($result) > 0) {
            // Records found
            return 1;
        } else {
            // No records found
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Main file:

```
<?php
include 'includes/pdo.include.php';

$example = new example;

echo $example->checkMail($_POST['email']);
?>
```

Comment: AMAZING!! ..Thank you so much.. But I have to ask you.. Isn't this just god damn annoying - that from now on you will need to expand 5 lines of code into 22 lines of code..?

Comment: Well, I think this looks cleaner than mysqli stuff. Also, you don't have to deal with escaping strings, and assigning values is cleaner. You get used to it, and in combination with OOP, this is some pretty good stuff.

Comment: no doubt.. the only thing I need now is to understand it and know how to use it... But everytime I am reading about it - it seems so meaningless to me.. -.-'

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get quite trough the documentation either. I just looked at some examples, tried to figure out what the statements did, and then build together my own stuff. But probably depends on what you're trying to do, which might increase the complexity (especially the query itself)